# How to locate texts in div.style tags using Watir?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I am fairly new to using Watir for automation. Here's the html source which I am working around with:

```html
<td align="left" class="list_vspace">


  <div style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;padding-top:8px; width:480px;">
    <div class="List_title">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="/images/icon_04.png" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="float:left;max-width:450px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"><a href="view.php?id=onmarket&amp;page=1&amp;divpage=661&amp;category=6&amp;no=3304222"><font color="#ACACAC">Mini pop-store</font></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both; font-size: 11px;font-family: &quot;arial&quot;;color:#acacac;">

      15:36:13 | Fish Market</div>

  </div>




</td>
```

My question is -

What's the script I need to write in order to locate the time and the text in the last div style (ie. 15:36:13 | Fish Market)?

I tried browser.div.style but it seems Watir doesn't recognize style for div. No where could I find an answer for this, google couldn't help as well, so I'm reaching out to you guys for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
browser.element(class: 'list_vspace').divs.last.text
 => "15:36:13 | Fish Market"
```

Answer (score 0):

To select an element by style, you need to use css. Notice that the spacing may be different on the input and output:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'google.com'
element = browser.element(css: "div[style='height:233px;margin-top:89px']")
element.exists? # => true
e2.style # => "height: 233px; margin-top: 89px;"
```

So you could do something like this for the code above:

```
browser.element(css: "div[style^='clear:both; font-size: 11px']").text
```